# mysql_fetch_assoc() returning unexpected value

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project where I use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to return an associative array.

However, I am puzzled as to why it would return `TRUE`

I have looked at the PHP manual page, and the only boolean value it should be returning is `FALSE`, and then only on a fail.

Although I am using a custom set of abstraction classes, it is *basically* doing this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE filename = 'test1.jpg'");
var_dump(mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); // bool(true)
```

Does anyone know why it would be returning `TRUE` instead of an array?

**Update**

Well, after trying a few things, I've determined its my library, as running the above code returns an associative array. I don't know why exactly it was returning `TRUE`, but for now, I am going to stop making things more complicated than they have to be (a problem of mine) and just use mysqli (thanks for the tip, Michael) instead of my own ActiveRecord classes, which apparently don't work.

Thanks!

Comment: How does the actual code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start using [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)  mysqli_fetch_assoc, .  The old version is soon to be outdated - the new one is better anyways.

Comment: "soon to be outdated - the new one is better anyways", the new one would be pdo then because there was a discussion to move _all_ non-pdo db extensions from the core to pecl. But this was postponed anyways; "current" snapshots of php 6 contain both php_mysql and php_mysqli

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same thing. It was a stupid coding error on my part.

I started out with:

```
$result = mysql_query($someSql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   // do stuff
}
```

which worked fine. Then I changed it to:

```
$result = mysql_query($someSql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) && $someCondition) {
   // do stuff
}
```

This is interpreted as `$row = (mysql_fetch_assoc($result) && $someCondition)`, which means `$row` becomes `true` while there are rows left and the second condition is `true`.

What I meant to write was:

```
$result = mysql_query($someSql);
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) && $someCondition) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
print_r (mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

It may give what you are looking for.

Oh, and silly me, var_dump () returns nothing, it directly outputs its findings like print_r ().

Comment: What does mysql_num_rows() say?  And what happens if you put the MySQL query into the db directly?